# Workflow In SPO

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, permissions, categories

Ok, I am going to try to best explain my SharePoint Online issue as clearly as possible since I have not found an answer searching through countless articles.

We are migrating items from SP2010 (on-prem) to SPO (Office 365 E3). We have a list containing documents and other PDFs grouped into categories for each department; this list is located on a subsite of the main site. What we need is to have permissions show each department only *their* category, not the categories for other departments. We did this on SP2010 via a workflow. I tried copying the workflow into SPO with a SP2010 platform on the main site, saved and published, (the original workflow had Impersonation Step which SPO does not), but when I log in as a test user I still see all categories. I see the workflow is activated on the subsite's list, but I am obviously missing something.

I could create a new App Part on the subsite for each of my departments and set permissions instead of using a Document List, but that would be a lot of work as we have a lot of departments and it is easier to update on a list rather having to click into each App Part.

So, to sum up, I want grouped users (either via AD or SP Group) to only see their items that is within their grouped department category on the subsite's list. An example of what I am asking is below:

**{When I log in as Admin}**

Important Stuff (SUBSITE NAME)

Important Documents (DOCUMENT LIST NAME)

+new item

column 1  column 2  column 3

Dept Group : HR

> Document 1
>
> Document 2
>
> PDF 1

Dept Group : IT

> Document 1
>
> Document 2
>
> Excel Sheet 1

Dept Group : Operations

> Excel Sheet 1
>
> Document 1
>
> PDF 1

Dept Group : Training

> PDF 1
>
> Document 1

**{When I log in as a member of the IT Group}**

Important Stuff (SUBSITE NAME)

Important Documents (DOCUMENT LIST NAME)

+new item

column 1  column 2  column 3

Dept Group: IT

> Document 1
>
> Document 2
>
> Excel Sheet 1

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Keith C.

Comment: Can you explain what this WF do? Is it breaks the permission of items/documents and add required group?

Comment: Sort of. The way we have it now on the old SP is once a specific group member goes to the subsite, all they see are the documents that are associated for their group. So the WF uses their group association to only show them their department's documents; they do not even see the other departments' items.

The documents themselves do not have any permissions associated to them.

Comment: So I ended up deleting the lists I had created and went with a more easily maintained idea. I created the lists that contains the information for each department seperately, threw user / group permissions on it, and created a hyperlink app part to house the links to the lists. This way I can protect the info at the initial "click on link", rather housing all info on one page and setting target audiences. The user now has to click one extra time, but I believe it will be easier in the long run for any SPAdmin that helps to maintain it later.

Comment: I ended up creating a bunch of lists with the associated groups as their titles and permissions. The web addresses are then set as a hyperlink for the groups, and then those hyperlinks are then placed on a "link" page where all users can see, but they can only access the lists in which they have permissions. Its the best work around I can find since my 2010 WF was not working on SPO...even though I set it to be a 2010 template when creating the workflow in SPD.